# ns timer duplicate created 2-3 times

Tags: ios, nstimer

I am working on a app in which i have created a timer which called method make sound every 1 sec..
after 10 sec it is invalidated automatically but on one button click event i have stopped timer before 10 sec complete,but when again i come to that view it creates two timer and the call method twice and for third it called same method 3 times

```
    DecilneTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(MakeSound) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and i have invalidate that like this on button click event

```
[DecilneTimer invalidate];
DecilneTimer=nil;
```

**how to solve duplicate creation of timer???**

Comment: What is `DecilneTimer`, where and how is it declared. BTW, the convention ios that variables and method names begin with a lowercase letter and class names begin with an uppercase letter. That makes understanding code easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
self.DecilneTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(MakeSound) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Using `self.propertyName = ...` you are using the property accessor and retaining the `NSTimer` automatically so that it doesnt get created again and again. And what you were doing was simply changing the ivar value directly

Comment: Either way ARC maintains the correct reference count.